# Animating Fragment causes other view to "jump"

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, transition

**Short Question:**

When using animation on FragmentTransactions, how can I animate other views with the animation?

**Long Question:**

Hi,

I am new to fragments and so on, and i am trying to animate them i a single activity so I created the following xml file for the activity:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/run_select_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_run_search_fragmentHeaderPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_run_search_fragmentPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I definded the res/anim files i want to use for the animation:

fade_in_from_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

fade_in_from_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

fade_out_to_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

fade_out_to_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

In detail: 
The lower fragment contains always a listview with several items. I do change the fragments based on what to search by a toggle button. thats no problem. When the user clicks on a specific listentry the headerFragment will be filled with additional data and displayed with a fade in animation like:

First show loading fragment while loading the data:

```
final RSBaseFragment headerFragment = (RSBaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activity_run_search_fragmentHeaderPlaceholder);

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
LoadingFragment fragment = new LoadingFragment();

if (headerFragment != null) {
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in_from_bottom, R.anim.fade_out_to_top, R.anim.fade_in_from_top, R.anim.fade_out_to_bottom);
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_run_search_fragmentHeaderPlaceholder, fragment, HEADER_FRAGMENT_TAG);
} else {
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in_from_top, R.anim.fade_out_to_bottom, R.anim.fade_in_from_bottom, R.anim.fade_out_to_top);
    ft.add(R.id.activity_run_search_fragmentHeaderPlaceholder, fragment, HEADER_FRAGMENT_TAG);
}
ft.commit();
```

After data was loaded show the data in a new fragment replacing the loading fragment

```
HeaderFragment fragment = new HeaderFragment();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in_from_top, R.anim.fade_out_to_bottom, R.anim.fade_in_from_bottom, R.anim.fade_out_to_top);
ft.replace(R.id.activity_run_search_fragmentHeaderPlaceholder, fragment, HEADER_FRAGMENT_TAG);
```

The problem ist that the headerfragment is fading and sliding in from the top or bottom direction, while the fragment holding the listview ist "jumping" to the bottom Y of the headerfragment before it's even there. How can I animate the lower fragment to slide with the header fragment to create a smooth user experience?

Sorry for the long question. If searched for 3 days and did not found anything helping with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nearly solved it by adding to the LinearLayout (run_select_fragment_container)

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

And in the onCreate of the Activity I have done this

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.run_select_fragment_container);
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = mainLayout.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```